# Scrapy traceback error (invalid syntax)

Tags: python, scapy

I've been following several tutorials and I'm obtaining `SyntaxError` continuously:

```
C:\Users\Luis\mercado>scrapy crawl mercado -t csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in 
<module>
    sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 
149,
in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
249,
in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
137,
in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
336,
in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", 
line 61, in from_settings return cls(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", 
line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", 
line 47, in _load_all_spiders
   for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", 
line 71
, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in 
import_module
    __import__(name)
      File "C:\Users\Luis\mercado\mercado\spiders\spider.py",     line 7
            Class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `class` is always written in lower case. You have a syntax error in your Python.

Comment: Hi!! Please could you help me?